# What database should I use for storing and analyzing blog post data warehouse? Relational vs No-SQL?

Tags: database, nosql

I plan to scrape blog posts from some sources and build a blog post data warehouse for analytics purpose. For example, listing the trending topics among millions of blog posts. I was wondering what type of database I should use for storing analyzing such big data. Relational or No-SQL? If No-SQL, which one?

I would appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Because the analytics you plan on running depend on the words inside each article, that sounds like a use case that could be addressed nicely by Elasticsearch (NoSQL)